# Entity Framework: Update-Database, when I'm not authorized to write to master

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, amazon-web-services

I have created a SQL Server database on Amazons Web Services. This means that I'm not authorized to edit the master database (or I believe so).

I followed the tutorial [code-first migrations with an existing database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/existing-database)

And I have been able to use the commands

```
Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges
```

But when I use this command

```
Update-Databse
```

I get this error

> This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database.  Unable to create a connection to the 'master' database  because the original database connection has been opened  and credentials have been removed from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.

And my connection string looks like this

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBContext" 
         connectionString="data source=DBName.ctekr2i3aabo.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;initial catalog=WeeklyReview;persist security info=True;user id=theodor349;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Did you try to change the connection string to initial catalog = master ?

Comment: Not sure if you removed it just for posting, but you haven't supplied a password for your user in your connection string.

Comment: Thanks. Had forgotten to enter the password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to supply the password for the connection.